# is there a code-coverage tool for the TSQL sproc unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, t-sql, code-coverage

I am looking for a unitttest and code-coverage tool for TSQL sprocs.  Can anyone recommend a good one? Commercial or free.

Answer (score 5):

For unit testing you can't really get better than tSQLt - the mocking functionality via FakeTable and SpyProcedure are really first rate and second to none.

If you use SSDT then you can use this to measure your code coverage:

https://the.agilesql.club/blog/Ed-Elliott/2016-01-14/T-SQL-Code-Coverage-In-SSDT

(I wrote it but that is exactly what it is for and is OSS)

I've got a version now that does not rely on ssdt and can be used as part of a build process:

https://the.agilesql.club/blogs/Ed-Elliott/2016-04-08/SQLCover-Code-Coverage-For-SQL-Server-T-SQL

ed

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find one either and so I just whipped one together:

https://github.com/jbarker7/sqlcc

It is an alpha release and doesn't have extensive documentation yet, but for the most part you should be able to modify the App.config and see the example and get it running for your database.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [tsqlunit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/), and just noticed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833233(VS.80).aspx) from Microsoft, which appears to be Database Unit Testing. There's a series of articles on Simple-Talk by [Alex Kuznetsov](http://www.simple-talk.com/author/alex-kuznetsov/) as well, for you to look at if you haven't already.

Comment: VSTS for Databases doesn't produce Sproc code coverage, unfortunately.  We ended up using SQLUnit as it's is easier to setup than VSTS for Databases.  Still looking for a good code coverage solution..

Comment: I'm interested in how this turns out. Might make my life easier too.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremiah Peschka started building dynamic T-SQL to call every stored proc in the database, but I haven't used this personally:

http://facility9.com/2009/02/16/automating-t-sql-testing